# Can I create a link on a web-page to dm someone on slack? (in a specific work-space)

Tags: slack-api

Can I create a link on a web-page to dm someone on slack? (in a specific work-space)

according to the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/deep-linking#open_a_direct_message), something like this should work

```
<a href="slack://user?team=TEAM-ID&id=USER-ID" target="_blank">
  click to dm me on slack
</a>
```

Where do I find the team id? Is it the subdomain in the workspace URL `TEAM-ID.slack.com`

When I tried this all it does is open slack to whatever was open last. I want it to open a direct message to the user whose user id is in the link.

**Update:** being that it is a little more complicated then I thought and I doubt I'll get a slack token from an admin, I'll be leaving it as is (just my slack username for people to find).

Comment: That link will only work if the user has a slack client installed. Wont work If he is only using the browser-based version.

Comment: The team ID is NOT the subdomain. You need to make an API call to get it, which means you need a token for that team. I recommend using `auth.test` for that, since it needs no scopes (https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test)

Comment: ok @ErikKalkoken I'll look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `team_id` comes along with any payload coming from the API. So you can just grab it there and pass it along as part of your link.

If you're just wanting to hardcode something in a webpage, you can get the `team_id` by calling the `team.info` method (https://api.slack.com/methods/team.info) with a test token.